# Set Radiobutton value form servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working on an Eclipse Project handling questions.
Right now, you can add a question. A question has the following properties : id, name and status (active or inactive).

When the user add a question, he can choose if the question is going to be active or inactive. (active per default)

In the case the user wants to update the question, I fill the different fields of the form with the existing values of the question.

Filling input text tag is working fine, but I can't find any solution to "recheck" the status of the question.

Here is the code of my servlet to fill the form with the existing value :

```
                 request.setAttribute( "nameValue", updateQuestion.getTitre() );
```

Below is the code of my JSP file containing the form :

```
<form action="questionController" method="post">
Subject : <input type="text" name="titre" value="${nameValue}"><br>
Status : <input type="radio" name="status" value="active">active
<input type="radio" name="status" value="inactive">inactive<br>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Send">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Cancel">
</form>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: you might be saving the status of the question in the DB as active or inactive 0 or 1 check it and show here by default

Comment: This is saved in the DB as 0 or 1, but how to set it in the jsp file from the controller?

Comment: DB-->Servlet--->JSP use a method which will allow you to add values after retrieving from DB and then follw this path to send to JSP.you can use javascirpt also to show data at run time